# Nodemon error in terminal when i try to run my server with it & after installing it gobally

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

```
$ nodemon index.js

[nodemon] 3.0.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
[nodemon] Error
    at Bus.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TALMEEZ AKHTAR\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\lib\nodemon.js:158:25)
    at Bus.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TALMEEZ AKHTAR\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\lib\monitor\run.js:180:9)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
[nodemon] unable to run executable: "node"
```

I already installed nodemon => `npm i -g nodemon`.

Comment: what happens if you run ```node -v``` ?

Comment: node -v
v18.17.1

Comment: My problem got fixed . I think their was some problem with directory . i tired to run nodemon in other directory it worked somehow . i am not sure how it worked but it did . Thank you sir for responding to my question .